# Integration of HTMl5 webgL with AUTOCAD

Tags: webgl, autocad

I would like to know whether it is possible to pass events from the browser to the rendered 3d AUTOCAD object. I was able to render the 3d object on the browser and was able to do the rotation, scaling operation. SO is it possible to pass commands from the browser to the AUTOCAD.

Kindly provide me your valuable inputs.

With Best Regards,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: The most compatible solution (Cross-browser, cross-version) will be AUTOCAD plugin with embedded server host that will communicate with browser in traditional way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a valuable info..1 doubt i have here as per http://usa.autodesk.com/autocad-ws/ i understand that we can only view 2d but not 3d objects..m i correct? and also can AUTOCAD WS be used on Windows platform

Comment: 3D http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJUkYHGjTHQ

Comment: Anyway you do not need to write own web server. For the beginning simple localhosts wamp server will do. You can write small AUTOCAD plugin that will directly interact with localhosts files and browser will interact with it thoughts http protocol.

Comment: JAre, I wan to put AUTOCAD WS in an iframe of my website where users can do their CAD operations and save the changes back to the server.In AUTOCAD WS we need to have a login account(i dont want my user who is accessing my website to have a login account with AUTOCAD WS).Is this possible with AUTOCAD WS? If no then is there any better approach to acheive the same..Thanks Sajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide that will help you with making an interactive 3D experience from an AutoCAD drawing and publish/view it online by using WebGL technology:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4RCYBMn-8I

Will exactly solve your case.